# Clicking on a row within a material-ui table and redirecting to another page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a file named route-names.js with the entry below

```
    export const REVIEW_FORM_URL = '/custom-forms/:customFormId';
```

I have a material-ui table with few rows and when I click on one for the rows the 
 id of the row can be seen as part of the url and it takes me to a blank screen.

```
     onClick(form) {
        this.props.history.push(REVIEW_FORM_URL.replace(':customFormId', form.customFormId));

      }
```

I need to build a new page that will use the value within that url.

where in the onClick code above can I place a redirection to the new page and how ?

The name of my new page is tester.js.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `this.props.history` I'll assume you are using some version of React Router.

If you want to go to another route in your application, using `history.push` is one of the possibilities.

If you push something in your history, you should have an element like this:

```html
<Route path="/theRouteIWantToGoTo/:customFormId" render={<ComponentTester />}
```

Somewhere in your code where `<ComponentTester />` renders what you need thanks to your tester.js render method.

Can you share more of your code?

Comment: I am completely new to react. The only thing I can see on this page is this  import {withRouter} from "react-router-dom";

Comment: my question is how can I modify the onClick code above to accept the parameter and redirect to the page I want?

Comment: You should have a file somewhere that describes which component should be rendered when a route is entered. When you go to your `REVIEW_FORM_URL`, something is rendered (your table probably).
What you need is to render something else when you click on a row. To do this, you have to "push" a new route in your `history` and render another component that satisfies your needs.